# How do I create an HTML multiplication table using DOM and user inputs

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm currently stuck on a problem that requires me to create a multiplication table based on User's input, however I am required to use DOM to create and edit the table. I'm able to create the tables, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to add in the numbers.

[Here's a link to the page so you can see what it looks like so far.](http://obsidian.sru.edu/users/btw1004/CPSC427/hw01.html)

```
<body>
    <h1>Brandon Wong</h1>
    <input id="num1"> rows x <input id="num2"> columns <input type="button" id="show" value="Show Table">
    <div id = "tablez"></div>
    <script>
        document.querySelector('input[type]').addEventListener('click', show_table);

        function show_table() {
            // get user's input
            const num1 = document.querySelector('#num1').value;
            const num2 = document.querySelector('#num2').value;

            //checks user's input
                //seems to not let you click "OK" sometimes, pressing Enter gets rid of prompt
            if (isNaN(num1) || isNaN(num2)){
                alert("Must input number");
                return false;
            }
            else{
                if ((num1 < 1 || num1 > 9) || (num2 < 1 || num2 > 9) ){
                    alert("Please enter a number between 1 and 9");
                }
                else {
                    const rows = [];
                    const columns = [];
                    for (var i = 0; i < num1; i++){
                        rows[i] = (i + 1);
                        //alert(rows[i]);
                    }

                    for (var i = 0; i < num2; i++){
                        columns[i] = (i + 1);
                        //alert(columns[i]);
                    }
                    
                    //create table
                    var table = document.createElement('table');
                    table.setAttribute('border', '1');
                    for (i = 0; i <= num1; i++){
                        var tr = document.createElement('tr');
                        for (j = 0; j <= num2; j++){
                            var td = document.createElement('td');
                            
                            tr.appendChild(td);
                        }
                        
                        table.appendChild(tr);
                    }
                    document.getElementById("tablez").appendChild(table);

                }
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

This is what the output should look like.
[image]
Any help is appreciated thanks!

Comment: Could you add your current result as well? When I look at the code, I think you get a runtime error at `rows[i] = (i + 1);`, but it will be easier to help out if with some more information about what is not working. You say you are able to create the table, so I assume you are able to create the correct number of columns and rows, but no numbers appear, am I right?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the columns and rows arrays, but I think you are getting a runtime error if you use them.

```
const rows = [];
const columns = [];
for (var i = 0; i < num1; i++){
  rows[i] = (i + 1); // runtime error here, because rows is empty. Array out of bounds error maybe.
  //alert(rows[i]);
}
for (var i = 0; i < num2; i++){
  columns[i] = (i + 1);
  //alert(columns[i]);
}
```

You could replace it with

```
const rows = [];
const columns = [];
for (var i = 0; i < num1; i++){
  rows.push((i + 1)); // add to existing array instead of assigning index that has not been created yet.
}
for (var i = 0; i < num2; i++){
  columns.push((i + 1))
}
```

Inside the createTable function, you never assign each cell a value. I will not give you the answer, but give you a hint as this question seems like an assignment.

```
var table = document.createElement('table');
table.setAttribute('border', '1');
for (i = 0; i <= num1; i++){
    var tr = document.createElement('tr');
    for (j = 0; j <= num2; j++){
        var td = document.createElement('td');
        // Here, you need to add a value yo your cell by multiplying the column and row values
        tr.appendChild(td);
    }
    
    table.appendChild(tr);
}
```

EDIT: [Here is a CodePen](https://codepen.io/johnedvard/pen/WNowBGK) with an incomplete result, but hopefully enough to help you figure out how to label the top row and left most column. From the comment, it seems to me that you are struggling with this part only.

In the following picture, I have marked the row and column counting zeros with pink. Why are all zeroes? Because you start the loop with the index 0, and `(0*j === 0)` and `(0*i===0)`, so each time the index is on the first row or column, our index is zero.

If we look at the row and column marked in green, aren't those the numbers we want to put in the first row and column? What if we tried to copy those numbers, but only on the first loop iteration? Or maybe we can input the correct values under certain conditions?

[image]

Comment: I appreciate the follow up. So I understand that I need to get the values in. However, what I am stuck on is how I am supposed to get my table looking like the picture I included in my original post. My original thought process was I could try and use the num2 values as the table headers. Should I make a separate loop to create the answers?

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can try this way

```js
document.querySelector('input[type]').addEventListener('click', () => {
  const num1 = document.querySelector('#num1').value;
  const num2 = document.querySelector('#num2').value;

  if (isNaN(num1) || isNaN(num2)) {
    alert("Must input number");
    return false;
  }

  if ((num1 < 1 || num1 > 9) || (num2 < 1 || num2 > 9)) {
    alert("Please enter a number between 1 and 9");
    return false;
  }

  let html = '<table border="1">';

  for (let i = 0; i <= num1; i++) {
    const label = i === 0 ? "" : i;
    html += `<tr><td>${label}</td>`;
    const multipler = i === 0 ? 1 : i;

    for (let j = 1; j <= num2; j++) {
      html += `<td>${multipler * j}</td>`;
    }

    html += "</tr>";
  }
  document.getElementById("tablez").innerHTML = html + '</table>';


});
```

```html
<h1>Brandon Wong</h1>
<input id="num1"> rows x <input id="num2"> columns <input type="button" id="show" value="Show Table">
<div id="tablez"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

So I was able to figure it out. It's a bit messy but it does it's job the way I want it to to display the output like the one in the screenshot above. What I did was use multiple for loops to be able to output it instead of trying to cram everything into one, which now looking back on it was pretty self explanatory.

```
 //create headers
                    var tr = document.createElement('tr');

                    //adds blank spot in first row
                    var thblank = document.createElement('th');
                    thblank.textContent = " ";
                    tr.appendChild(thblank);

                    //adds column headers
                    for (i = 0; i < num2; i++){
                        var th = document.createElement('th');
                        th.textContent = i + 1;
                        tr.appendChild(th);
                    }
                    table.appendChild(tr);
                    
                    for (i = 0; i < num1; i++){
                        //creates tr for entire row of data
                        var tr = document.createElement('tr');
                        //creates the left most margin of numbers for each row
                        var tdfirst = document.createElement('td');
                        tdfirst.textContent = i + 1;
                        tdfirst.style.fontWeight = 'bold';
                        tr.appendChild(tdfirst);
                        //computation of multiplication table
                        for (j = 0; j < num2; j++){
                            var td = document.createElement('td');
                            td.textContent = ((i+1) * (j+1));
                            tr.appendChild(td);
                        }
                        table.appendChild(tr);
                    }
                    document.getElementById("tablez").appendChild(table);
```

Comment: I am happy you were able to figure it out on your own. Good work, and good luck :D There are many ways to come to a solution. Each solution has it pros and cons. Usually, if you want a performant solution, readability and maintainability will suffer, and vice-versa.